# \renewcommand causing problems with \author

Tags: macros, author

I have the following document.
This is the preamble:

```
\def\year{2017}\relax
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.8cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{aaai17}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, bm, mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dsfont} %for probability P
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\bf}[1]{\textit{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Title}
\author{Foo \AND Bar}
```

This is the document:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

When compiling I received the following error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
} l.77 \maketitle
```

When I delete the line `\renewcommand{\bf}[1]{\textit{#1}}` or delete the `\AND` character in `\author{Foo \AND Bar}`, the document compiles normally. Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix? (Assuming I want to both redefine `\bf` and use `\AND` in `\author`)

**EDITED:** I just changed newline to `\AND` and got the same problem. As @UlrikeFischer points out, the use of `aaai17` causes the problem. Note that the symbol `\AND` is only available in this package. What is wrong with this package?

Comment: I don't have \usepackage{aaai17} and without it it works fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for pointing out. Do you know why the package causes problems? I use it to split the article into 2 columns.

Comment: As I wrote: I don't have the package so I can't know what it does. But try `\let\bf\itshape` instead of your definition .

Comment: `\bf` is not a command with arguments; use `\renewcommand{\bf}{\itshape}`.

Comment: @egreg I used `\renewcommand{\bf}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` in other documents and it works fine...

Comment: @thbl2012 You were very lucky.

Answer (score 1):

The command `\bf` has been deprecated for almost 25 years, but apparently this long time hasn't been sufficient in order for package authors and maintainers to comply with this deprecation.

However, the command has ***never*** taken an argument: it is a declaration meaning “change to normalfont and then start typesetting in boldface” until the scope of the declaration ends.

If you want that boldface called with `\bf` becomes italic, the right instruction is

```
\renewcommand{\bf}{\itshape}
```

that is, substituting a declaration with another one.

With your code, since `\AND` in `aaai17` is defined to be `\end{tabular}`, with `\bf\AND` you and up with `\textit{\end}{tabular}` which is very wrong code and, not surprisingly, causes a later error. Your redefinition has always been wrong to begin with.